# How to retrieve document in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have multiple document in collection having a long string in each document, I want to retrieve one document at time, I dont have anything in document except long string, how can I retrieve that?

I inserted all document in collection using insertMany(), here is my code and output when I retrieved all document

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
question : String,
id: Number
})

var quizz = mongoose.model('Quiz', schema );

var firstDoc = new quizz({
question: 'question 1',
id: 1
})
var secondDoc = new quizz({
question: 'question 2',
id: 2

var question_data = [firstDoc, secondDoc];

quizz.insertMany(question_data, function(err, res){
  if(err){
   console.log("error occured while saving document object " + err )
 }else{
   console.log("saved data");
 }
})

quizz.findOne({id : '1'}, function(err, res){
if(err){
console.log(err)
}else{
  console.log(res);     
}
})
```

[image]

Comment: `quizz.findOne(function(err, data) {  })`

Comment: I have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

`insertMany` Will return you the list of `_id`s that have been created for your documents you've inserted. You can then pull out each document based on the `_id`s individually

```
quizz.insertMany(question_data, function(err, res){
  if(err){
   console.log("error occured while saving document object " + err )
 }else{
   console.dir(res); // res has the _ids.
   console.log("saved data");
 }
})
```

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.insertMany

Alternatively if you always want to ensure ordering you could add a sequence column to the question, and/or put all questions inside one quizz.

Comment: what if we want to retrieve a single document in the collection? I asked this question because I have no anything that is distinct in documents except string I'm saving which is very long I cant write whole question and say if this matches ant document give it to me, and ID which is assigned by mongoose itself, which is also very long

Comment: I think you'll just want a sequence on each documen then and query it using the following `quizz.findOne({ sequence: 1 }, function (err, doc) { })`

Comment: If I'm doing this Im getting null

Comment: You'll need to set the `sequence` field to each of the documents first.

Comment: instead of sequence I added id :) outputting right value

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do something with the _id of the documents that was inserted into the collection then use the answer of Kevin, but if you want to just do something with them later, you can use `.find()` which return you all the documents that are in the collection.

```
quizz.find(function(err, docs) {
  //docs = array of all the docs in the collections
})
```

if you want specific by id:

```
quizz.findOne({_id: id},function(err, doc) {
  //doc = the specific doc
})
```

if you want specific by strong

```
quizz.findOne({question: "question 3"},function(err, doc) {
  //doc = the first (!!!) doc that have question in his `question` attribute 
})
```

or if you  want all the docs that have question 3 in them:

```
quizz.find({question: "question 3"},function(err, docs) {
  //docs = array with all the docs that have "question 3" there, (return array even if only 1 found) 
})
```

Comment: yes I added id as new property into schema and eventually in document, so that I can identify each document

Comment: Well you should edit the question to tell us exactly what you want to do achieve, because you don't need to add id to the document as mongoose handle it as soon as you save a document (without id)

Comment: If I'm adding new property id and retrieving using findOne(id: number) Im getting null

Comment: Its local one, local id not that assigned by mongoose

Comment: what you get in `err`?

Comment: nothing but when I added some text with err in findOne method like this console.log("Error " + err) the console outputting value, why this happend

Comment: what? what is the output you are getting? if you do `console.log(err)` you get nothing?

Comment: please edit the question with the code and outputs so we can understand better.

Comment: yes :) previously, first time I got nothing but now Im getting right value

Comment: one thing I want to ask is my structure is right, i.e I'm adding new property id to uniquely identify each document

Comment: why do you need this if mongoose already giving you id? i saw many who don't encourage as it really have no benefits.

Comment: because to identify each document I will have to pass long mongoose produced id to findOne function, thats why

Comment: once you will have about over 1000 documents you will need to remember longish ids as well, if you plan on remember ids then don't, you won't, and you will find your self connecting to the database to check the id (and than it won't matter if you copy the 9897 id or the mongo id), if you will find the id other way, then it won't matter if its long or short.